# Android: How to remove out-of-place semi-transparent layer and pressed effects?

Tags: android, button

Couple years ago I noticed, that on several buttons (Widget.ImageButton) an extra semi-transparent layer was visible. For longest time I paid no attention to it, but lately on some configurations this semi-transparent layers looks quite bad and out of place. Also, when a button is pressed, the shadow effect doesn't match the dimensions of the button:
[image]

Since I have a background for focused and pressed states, I dont need any extra stuff over my buttons.
From what I've read, this is a default android thing: a button attribute colorControlHighlight, introduced with Lollipop version?

Update: Thanks to Mike M. for suggesting android:stateListAnimator="@null". That solved the issue.

Comment: That does look like the native shadow glitch, and if it is, it's not "over" the button. It's actually behind it, and you're seeing it because the button has a transparent or translucent background. If that's the case, the simplest fix is to just use solid colors for the background instead. If you actually need to see through the button, then that'll take some sort of workaround, AFAIK.

Comment: I should've also mentioned that if you don't really need or want the shadow at all, you can get rid of it altogether on a `Button` by setting its `android:stateListAnimator="@null"`, or the equivalent in code. (You'd want to make sure that its elevation and z-translation are zero, too, but those aren't usually set separately for `Button`s.)

Comment: android:stateListAnimator="@null" worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike M. for suggesting android:stateListAnimator="@null". That solved the issue.